# Dominated convergence theorem to prove the boundedness of a stopping time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stopping-times

I encountered an argument that I could not follow. Here are the setting (that I simplified) and my question. Thank you in advance!

Time is discrete: $t \in \mathbb{N}$. Consider an adapted stochastic process $(X_{t})_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ on a (standard) filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_{t})_{t \in \mathbb{N}},\mathbb{P})$.
For some $N \in \mathbb{N}$, we also have a finite probability space:
\begin{align*}
\left(
    \tilde{\Omega}=\left\{1,2,\ldots,2^{N}\right\},~
    \tilde{\mathcal{F}}=2^{\tilde{\Omega}},~
    \tilde{\mathbb{P}}=\left\{p_{1},p_{2},\ldots,p_{2^{N}}\right\}
\right).
\end{align*}
Assume that a random variable $Y$ defined on $(\tilde{\Omega},\tilde{\mathcal{F}},\tilde{\mathbb{P}})$ takes one of the $2^{N}$ different values, denoted $y^{1} < y^{2} < \cdots < y^{2^{N}}$.

Suppose that there is an almost surely finite stopping time $\sigma \ge 0$ such that:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X_{\sigma} \ge y^{i}) > \tilde{\mathbb{P}}(Y \ge y^{i})
\qquad
\forall\, i = 1,2,\ldots,2^{N}.
\end{align*}
Note that $\mathbb{E}[X_{\sigma}] < \infty$ (as pointed out by Math1000).

I encountered the following argument:

*The Dominated Convergence Theorem implies $T \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X_{\sigma \wedge T} \ge y^{i}) \ge \tilde{\mathbb{P}}(Y \ge y^{i})
\qquad
\forall\, i = 1,2,\ldots,2^{N}.
\end{align*}
Hence, we have the bounded stopping time $\tau \equiv \sigma \wedge T$.*

I had no idea how the dominated convergence theorem is used in this context? Thank you.

Comment: Since $\sigma$ is nonnegative is almost surely finite, presumably $\mathbb E[X_\sigma]<\infty$ and so $X_\sigma$ is your dominating random variable.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it is assumed that $\mathbb{E}[X_{\sigma}] < \infty$. (I should have written. Sorry.) Could you please explain "$X_{\sigma}$ is your dominating random variable" in more detail? I still cannot see how the dominated convergence theorem is used.

Comment: Generally the dominated convergence theorem is used to prove that if $X_n\to X$ a.s. and $|X_n|\leqslant Y$ a.s. for some $Y$ with $\mathbb E[|Y|]<\infty$, then $\mathbb E[X_n]\to\mathbb E[X]$. Here I see no expectations so I am not sure how the DCT is being used either.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Since $\mathbb{P}(E) = \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{E}]$ for an event $E$, I actually tried to use the DCT. Nevertheless, it didn't work...